# Show that integrated track length in electromagnetic shower is proportional to $E_0$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, particle-detectors

I would like to show that the integrated track length in an electromagnetic shower is proportional to $E_0$. The energy spectrum of the shower is modeled by, $E(t)=\frac{E_0}{2^t}$, where $t$ refers to the time it takes for the particle to traverse a single radiation length, $x_0$. That is, the distance it travels before splitting into two secondaries. It is also known that the shower terminates at $E=E_c$.

The integrated track length should therefore simply be the radiation length, $x_0$ multiplied by the total number of particles traversing this length until $t_{max}=t_{c}$, where $t_{max}=\log_2(E_0/E_c)$. We therefore have that, $$T_{int}=x_0\int_0^{t_{max}}2^t\,dt=\frac{x_0}{\ln(2)}(\frac{E_0}{E_c}-1).$$

Evidently, this is not exactly proportional to $E_0$, differing by a constant, $-\frac{x_0}{\ln(2)}$. I feel as if there is something wrong with my bounds of integration, though I'm not exactly certain what. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm making sense, but I think it has something to do with the fact that there are a discrete number of particles per generation. I think the integral should actually be a sum. You do not generate new particles for every infinitesimal $t$, but only for $t+n$, where $n$ is an integer, until $t+n=t_{max}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct. Yes, we must sum over all track lengths. However, using an integral to achieve this merely gives an approximation. As per my comment above, daughter particles are only produced at discrete times, $t_0+n$, where $n$ is an integer, until, $t_0+n=t_{max}$. That is to say, we do not produce particles at $t_0+0.5=0.5$. In truth, therefore, we really should be taking a sum, not an integral.

Regardless, the integral still works well enough for our purposes. We have (as you have correctly stated), $$T_{int}=x_0\int_0^{t_{max}}2^t\,dt=\frac{x_0}{\ln(2)}(\frac{E_0}{E_c}-1).$$

Again, you are correct that the proportionality differs by a constant. However, consider what it means for $E_0$ to equal $E_c$, which is the termination energy. Simply, no shower will occur, for $E_0\approx E_c$, and so, we can argue that $1=\frac{E_c}{E_c}\ll \frac{E_0}{E_c}$, such that the $1$ is negligible, and that $$T_{int}=\frac{x_0}{E_c\cdot\ln(2)}E_0,$$

which is certainly proportional to $E_0$.

Comment: Ah, okay, I kind of see. To clarify, the integral is approximate because the production of daughter particles is a discrete process?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. You aren't producing daughter particles every instant -- only after some discrete time corresponding to the radiation length.